# What exactly does it mean that Android 12 notification is set as silent?

Tags: notifications, android-12, realme

I have realized today that I haven't seen any kind of notification that there are app updates available for months. And the only way to actual know about this fact is to (accidentally or not) visit Google Play app:

[image]

If so then how should I understand this part:

[image]

What exactly is "notification drawer"? Where should I see those notifications?

The truth is that the only way (other than described above) to learn that some app has an update available is when that particular app has "update check" and warns me upon opening it that I should update it.

How can I "see them in notification drawer" if I don't see them absolutely nowhere through the system (except for Google Play app an the app in question itself)?

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications#bar-and-drawer

Comment: ...and how should this link help me understanding why my Google Play app does not show any notification in app drawer even though marked piece of my screenshot show that it should?

Comment: It explains exactly what the "notification drawer" is. To my understanding you have to pull down and see the full notification drawer to see the notifications. If you don't see them then this can be a bug of your OS or the description is simply wrong.

Comment: @Robert Your latest comment actually answers my question and resolves my problem. Turning it into answer, linking what you have linked, would in my opinion bring us a valuable answer here. I'd more that happy to accept is, should you decide to write it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [description by Google](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications#bar-and-drawer) the **notification drawer** is the common section where all notifications are visible after swiping down from status bar:

> Users can swipe down on the status bar to open the notification drawer, where they can view more details and take actions with the notification.
>
> [image]

Therefore silent notifications should appear just like regular notifications but without any hint to you outside of the notification drawer. So if you don't swipe down the status bar you won't recognize that there is a new notification.